# what does the term 'Promise-based Http client' mean?

Tags: reactjs, http, https, axios

While going through the Redux middleware, I have come across Axios which is 'Promise-based HTTP client' to make Ajax request from browser. Could any body explain about this term and some info about axios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise-based client returns promises rather than accepting callbacks.

Comment: A--Basically i didn't understand what promise is. Could you explain or provide any link that i can go through?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thank You @Ryan A.

Answer (score 6):

Before `Promise's` comes into the picture there is something called `Callback` to handle asynchronous calls/code. But the main issue with callback is that when it gets nested and more nested it becomes very messy code and harder to understand even for the writer of the code.

To make it bit cleaner `Promise` comes into the picture which is cleaner in nature, Avoid callback hell problem in nodejs programming.

Moreover the concept `async/await` is also best fit with the promise instead of callback.

Hope you understand now. Comment below in case of any doubt.

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> A `Promise` is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the
> promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an
> asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This
> lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods:
> instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous
> method returns a *promise* to supply the value at some point in the
> future.
>
> A `Promise` is in one of these states:
>
> - *pending*: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
> - *fulfilled*: meaning that the operation was completed successfully.
> - *rejected*: meaning that the operation failed.

Comment: This answer appears to be copied from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

When providing an external source in your answers, it's best to link to the source and quote the copied text so that the original source is properly credited and onlookers are able to view the source for full context.